# Работа с webcam

Tags: java

Как на java открыть webcam, сохранить изображение, перехватить видео поток для видеоконференции?

Comment: посмотри в сторону jmf

Comment: jmf, JMyron просмотрел. JMyron не работает, на нашел полной нормальной информации, библиотек.
jmf пишут, уже как 15 не развивается?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ тут:
http://r28forum.ru/index.php?topic=76.0

Comment: Только учтите, что этот способ плохо переносим. Скорее всего мало где будет работать. И далеко не все камеры поддерживаются, так как не все форматы реализованы.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture.
У меня аналогичная задача. Тоже долго искал решение. И переносимость неплохая.